# Insert query using foreach

Tags: codeigniter-3

I'm trying to generate a statement sheet. For that, I try to insert data into Mysql using foreach. It works great. But I try to escape the insert query if any duplicate row found in database. I do not want to escape the whole process, but it should escape if a duplicate row found and continue with the next insert query.

```
$gps = $this->Webmastermodel->acquireStatementDetail();

foreach($gps as $statement){

$insertdata = array(
'product_invoice_id' => $statement['InvoiceNo'],
'PUC' => $statement['productPUC'],
'productQTY' => $statement['productQty'],
'product_sub_total' => $statement['productSubTotal'],
'commissionGain_on_SubTotal' => $statement['commisionChargedOnProductSubTotal']
    );

$this->db->insert('partner_business', $insertdata);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `insert_batch` if i were you:

```
$insertdata = array();
foreach($gps as $statement)
{

    $insertdata[] = array(
    'product_invoice_id' => $statement['InvoiceNo'],
    'PUC' => $statement['productPUC'],
    'productQTY' => $statement['productQty'],
    'product_sub_total' => $statement['productSubTotal'],
    'commissionGain_on_SubTotal' => $statement['commisionChargedOnProductSubTotal']
        );
}

$this->db->insert_batch('partner_business', $insertdata);
```

---

But since your question is about skipping if a row already exits, you can modify your query and use `replace` instead:

```
$this->db->replace('partner_business', $insertdata);
```

Keeping in mind that its all about providing the right `primary_key` in your `$data` array, if there is and existing id it will `update` its data else it will `insert` a new row.

Comment: thanks for suggesting to use insert_batch. I updated my code as you suggested. but please help me in escaping the duplicate value. i tried replace. but it does not work. please guide me in detail.

Comment: Replace really depends on the `primary_key` if you provided the right one it will just update it, if it was null it will insert a new one, i've tested it thoughtfully myself.

Comment: Is there any alternate way?

Comment: Every other way is a very nasty one, you wouldn't want to loop on a `check for existance` else `insert` it will generate double the queries, so forget about this already ... OR you can use a raw sql query and put it in a `$this->db->query($query)` and it should work and you will find a a lot of answers about insert if not exist mysql query here on stackoverflow ... but i still insist `replace should work just fine if you have all the right data with associated ids!

Comment: Ok but how replace can be used with insert_batch.

Comment: @KUNDANKUMAR .. Codeigniter doesn't support `replace_batch` so you have to depend on either raw sql query and you will find tons of pure sql queries out there that will perfectly get the job done or rely on `DELETE` then `INSERT_BATCH` (as you will delete all matching results then insert all of your data) or you can stick with your code above with replacing `insert` with `replace`.